# Limpar um listview que esta inflado com um layout inflater, Android C#

Tags: c#, android, listview, adapter

Bom estou com o seguinte problema, eu usei um layout `inflater` para preencher um `listview` com uma `adapter` mas eu quero limpar esse `adapter`, pois os produtos contidos na lista não mudando quando clico em outra categoria de produtos, Exemplo: aparece as categorias e ao clicar em uma categoria lista os produtos relacionadas a mesma mas quando clico em outra categoria aparece os mesmo produtos, alguém tem uma ideia de como limpar o layout `inflater` ou o `adapter` pois eu não sei onde fazer essa modificação.

Meu código activymain:

```
var cateListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listViewcategorias);
                    //Toast.MakeText(this, dt.Rows.Count.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    cateListView.FastScrollEnabled = true;
                    // cateListView.ItemClick += FilmesListView_ItemClick;
                    categoriasAdapter.dt = dt;
                    var filmesAdapter = new categoriasAdapter(this, FilmesRepositorio.cate);   
                    cateListView.Adapter = filmesAdapter;
                    cateListView.ItemClick += FilmesListView_ItemClick;
```

Meu listadapter:

```
public class produtoAdapter : BaseAdapter<produto>
    {
        private readonly Activity context;
        private readonly List<produto> prod;
        public static DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        public produtoAdapter(Activity context, List<produto> pro)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.prod = pro;

        }
        public override produto this[int position]
        {
            get
            {
                return prod[position];
            }
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return prod.Count;
            }
        }



        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return prod[position].Id_prod;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            //context.Recreate();
            //var view = convertView ?? context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.vprodutos, parent, false);  
            context.LayoutInflater.Dispose();
            var view = convertView = this.context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.vprodutos, parent, false);
            try
            { 
                var txtproduto = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtproduto);
                var txtvalorproduto = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtvalorproduto);
                txtproduto.Text = prod[position].descricao;
                txtvalorproduto.Text = prod[position].valor.ToString("0.00");
                Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "adiconou" + prod[position].descricao, ToastLength.Short).Show(); 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, ex.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
            return view;
        }
    }
```

Comment: E onde você está alterando o `dt`?

Comment: No oncliki quando cliko em uma categoria ele alterar a dt chamando um metodo que carrega ele com as informações e passam para o adapter e depois para o list.

Answer (score 0):

No oncliki quando cliko em uma categoria ele alterar a dt chamando um metodo que carrega ele com as informações e passam para o adapter e depois para o list.